# What happens between a java controller and jsp

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a java controller.In this controller i have a string array("Cities") which consisits of nearly 3000 strings. Now my problem is when i am sending it to the JSP page and trying it to display, it s taking too much time.

My Observations :

1) First i thought database access, from where i am fetching these cities is taking time. But it s not.
2)Second i thought displaying these cities in the dropdown is taking time. But it is not

So i would like to know what is reali happening to the data between a controller and jsp. What process is going on between

```
 models.put("cities", cities);
 return new  ModelAndView("traning_management", models);
```

variable cities contains nearly 3000 cities.

Answer (score 0):

The `ModelAndView` [constructor](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-webmvc/4.2.0.RELEASE/org/springframework/web/servlet/ModelAndView.java#94) is harmless. It stores the view name and copies the provided map entries into a `LinkedHashMap` (in your case there is only one entry, an array of name strings).

Comment: This is taking too much time. Is there any other way i can send large string array to jsp page in an efficient. The transfer is taking time

Comment: my cities array is a sortedset.  SortedSet<String> cities = new TreeSet<String>();